# Lowest Common Ancestor Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree, traversal, least-common-ancestor

So I have been looking into implementing a lowest common ancestor algorithm. I looked at many different algorithms (mainly variations of Trajan's solution or variations of the RMQ).

I am using a non-binary tree. My tree will often change between queries and therefore pre-processing wouldn't necessarily be worthwhile. The tree shouldn't have more than 50-75 nodes. What I am wondering is whether I should bother using their algorithms or just stick with my own.

My Algorithm

```
myLCA(node1, node2) {
    parentNode := [ ]
    while (node1!=NULL) {
         parentNode.push(node1)
         node1 := node1.parent
    }
     while (node2!=NULL) {
         for i in parentNode.size {
             if (parentNode(i) == node2) {
                 return node2; 
             }
         }
         node2 := node2.parent
     }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this is a real question. What type of answer do you expect to receive?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your algorithm is currently quadratic.  That may not be a problem for a dataset as small as 50-75 nodes, but in any case it's straightforward to change it to linear time without using any sets or hashtables, just by recording the complete path to the root for each node, then walking back down from the root and looking for the first different node.  The immediately preceding node (which is the common parent of these 2 different nodes) is then the LCA:

```
linearLCA(node1, node2) {
    parentNode1 := [ ]
    while (node1!=NULL) {
         parentNode1.push(node1)
         node1 := node1.parent
    }
    parentNode2 := [ ]
    while (node2!=NULL) {
         parentNode2.push(node2)
         node2 := node2.parent
    }
    while (node1 == node2 && !isEmpty(parentNode1) && !isEmpty(parentNode2)) {
        oldNode := node1
        node1 := parentNode1.pop()
        node2 := parentNode2.pop()
    }
    if (node1 == node2) return node1    // One node is descended from the other
    else return oldNode                 // Neither is descended from the other
}
```

**EDIT 27/5/2012:** Handle the case in which one node is descended from the other, which would otherwise result in attempting to `pop()` an empty stack.  Thanks to damned for pointing this out.  (I also realised that it's sufficient to track a single `oldNode`.)

Comment: Modification : In languages like java, pop() can throw EmptyStackException, which should be handled either by Exception Handling or by checking the sizes of both stacks before popping.

Comment: @damned: Actually that's not necessary, because the fact that `node1` and `node2` belong to the same tree guarantees that a common ancestor will be found in the final `while` loop -- neither of those calls to `pop()` can possibly fail.

Comment: The exception will always occur if we have one node to be the descendant of the other. Take a parent-child pair for example.

Comment: @damned: You're quite right, my apologies. I'll update in a moment to fix that.

Comment: still its not handling properly for one node is descended from other i think.  
Say list1 has 3 elements and list2 has 2 elements. After running while twice it has problem.

Comment: @NRK: Assuming you mean the case when `node1` is a child of `node2`: That case seems to work for me when I write down the states after each step.  The `while` condition is tested 3 times: the first time, `node1` and `node2` are both `null`, the second time they are both equal to the root node, the third time they are both equal to the 2nd node in the path from the root (this will be `node2` itself) but `parentNode2` is empty so the loop exits and `if (node1 == node2) return node1` succeeds. Note that `node1` gets modified inside the function -- it won't return the original value passed in.

Answer (score 4):

For a tree that small, I wouldn't bother implementing anything more complex. Your solution looks good, although the time complexity is squared in terms of the height of the tree. If you can easily implement a `Set` (most languages have it built-in), then the algorithm could be tweaked to,

1. Traverse from the first node up to the root and collect all nodes in a set
2. Traverse from the second node up to the root and check if the current node exists in that set. If it does, then that is the common ancestor.

Also, this algorithm assumes that a node can be its own ancestor. Otherwise, you would have to tweak the algorithm slightly. Consider this example,

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

When trying to find the lowest common ancestor of B, and C, this algorithm would report B, which may or may not be true depending on how you define ancestor.

Answer (score 3):

Without looking at the details of either algorithm, I'd suggest looking at how important the efficiency of this algorithms is to your overall application, and how much effort would be required to implement another algorithm.

How many times will this algorithm be run in normal (or stressed) operation of your application? Will it cause the user to wait longer than necessary? Are the other algorithms of a different order of magnitude faster than yours? (Someone familiar with the algorithms can give you a more detailed answer on this.)

I think it is not worth optimising a bit of code unless you will see sizable results (some people feel quite strongly that premature optamisation is [the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization))

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is quadratic, but it can easily be made linear.

Just use hashtable (i.e. set) for `parentNode`, instead of list.
Thus checking whether a node is in `parentNode` will be `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a blog post about how I had to implement my own algorithm for this problem but extended to a set of nodes with an arbitrary length.
You can find it here (with a step-by-step graphical explanation of how it works)

http://bio4j.com/blog/2012/02/finding-the-lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-set-of-ncbi-taxonomy-nodes-with-bio4j/

Cheers,

Pablo

Comment: The direct link does not work for me, however if you google for it, you'll get to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have one simplistic solution 
sort the two elements and the lowest be left and highest be right
visit root
def recurse(root)
return nil if root.empty?
if left <= root && right >= root
  return root
elsif left <= root && right <= root
  recurse(root.left)
else 
  recurse(root.right)
end

So this will check on each traversal 
The problem soluted in O(log n) time for average and worst and O(log